# How to Async.AwaitTask on plain Task (not Task<T>)?

Tags: f#, async-await

I'm trying to consume a C# library in F#. The library makes heavy use of async/await. I want to use within an `async { ... }` workflow in F#.

I see we can `Async.AwaitTask` on async C# methods returning `Task<T>`, but what about those returning plain `Task`?

Perhaps, is there a helper to convert these to `Async<unit>` or to convert `Task` to `Task<unit>` so it will work with `Async.AwaitTask`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use ContinueWith:

```
let awaitTask (t: Task) = t.ContinueWith (fun t -> ()) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Or AwaitIAsyncResult with infinite timeout:

```
let awaitTask (t: Task) = t |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult |> Async.Ignore
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Of course, Task is an IAsyncResult after all. Shortened to `let awaitTask = Async.AwaitIAsyncResult >> Async.Ignore` Thanks much!

Comment: ContinueWith is not idiomatic F#, plus it's dangerous because it could throw TaskCanceledException

Answer (score 18):

**Update:**

The FSharp.Core library for F# 4.0 now includes an `Async.AwaitTask` overload that accepts a plain `Task`. If you're using F# 4.0 then you should use this core function instead of the code below.

---

**Original answer:**

If your task could throw an exception then you probably also want to check for this. e.g.

```
let awaitTask (task : Task) =
    async {
        do! task |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult |> Async.Ignore
        if task.IsFaulted then raise task.Exception
        return ()
    }
```

Comment: `raise task.Exception` will just raise the AggregateException; it's probably better to access its `InnerExceptions` collection, and raise the first one (so long as the collection isn't empty)

Answer (score 15):

**Update:**

The FSharp.Core library for F# 4.0 now includes an Async.AwaitTask overload that accepts a plain Task. If you're using F# 4.0 then you should use this core function instead of the code below.

**Original answer:**

I really liked Ashley's suggestion using function composition. Additionally, you can extend the Async module like this:

```
module Async =
    let AwaitTaskVoid : (Task -> Async<unit>) =
        Async.AwaitIAsyncResult >> Async.Ignore
```

Then it appears in Intellisense along with Async.AwaitTask. It can be used like this:

```
do! Task.Delay delay |> Async.AwaitTaskVoid
```

Any suggestions for a better name?

Answer (score 1):

To properly propagate both exceptions and cancellation properly, I *think* you need something like this (partially based on deleted answer by Tomáš Petříček):

```
module Async =
    let AwaitVoidTask (task : Task) : Async<unit> =
        Async.FromContinuations(fun (cont, econt, ccont) ->
            task.ContinueWith(fun task ->
                if task.IsFaulted then econt task.Exception
                elif task.IsCanceled then ccont (OperationCanceledException())
                else cont ()) |> ignore)
```