# How to download big files using the http module of FSharp.Data?

Tags: f#, f#-data

The following code snippet is found in the FSharp.Data website http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html. The type of `Text` and `Binary` are `string` and `byte[]` respectively. It's not good to get the whole 2GB file in memory and then save it to a file.

```
let logoUrl = "https://raw.github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/master/misc/logo.png"
match Http.Request(logoUrl).Body with
| Text text -> 
    printfn "Got text content: %s" text
| Binary bytes -> 
    printfn "Got %d bytes of binary content" bytes.Length
```

Comment: `Http.RequestStream(logoUrl).ResponseStream.CopyTo(outStream)` seems like it would do it.

Comment: Nice, dose it need to check if the returned `Response` object of `RequestStream` and `ResponseStream` are not null?

Comment: Considering that this is an F#-specific library, I would guess no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can keep the same code as on the `FSharp.Data` website to download huge files.
What I use to download large files is

```
async {
    let! request = Http.AsyncRequestStream(logoUrl)
    use outputFile = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName,System.IO.FileMode.Create)
    do! request.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync( outputFile ) |> Async.AwaitTaskVoid 
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

If you want to try to download infinite file check [the complete source](https://github.com/davidpodhola/sagacious-octo-kumquat/blob/master/Download%20Big%20Files%2024870998/BigFilesDownloader/Program.fs) (run on your own risk, it is using the [The Infinite File Download](http://infinite-download.ma.ttias.be/))

Comment: AwaitTaskVoid is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022909/how-to-async-awaittask-on-plain-task-not-taskt