# How can I define an owin middleware class in F#?

Tags: f#, owin

I am trying to create the example class below (taken from [here](http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-write-owin-middleware-in-5-different-steps)) in F#.

```cs
public class LoggingMiddleware
{
    private AppFunc next;

    public LoggingMiddleware(Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Request");
        await next.Invoke(environment);
        Console.WriteLine("End Request");
    }
}
```

However, I'm struggling both with converting between the typical .NET types and the typical F# types and using the F# async workflows to achieve what is happening with the C# await.

Comment: You will get better help here if you post at least some of your F# code.

Comment: Have a google for dyfrig too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest (current) issue with F# async workflows and .Net task is that there is no direct analogy to a `Task` that has no return type.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8022955/612512), I'll use this function binding to await Tasks with no return value:

```ml
let awaitTask = Async.AwaitIAsyncResult >> Async.Ignore
```

With that, you can directly translate your example class to:

```ml
type FSharpMiddleware(next: Func<IDictionary<string,obj>, Task>) =

    member this.Invoke (environment: IDictionary<string,obj>) : Task =
        async {
            printfn "Begin Request"
            do!
                awaitTask <| next.Invoke environment
            printfn "End Request"
        } |> Async.StartAsTask :> Task
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for.  Thank you!  Hopefully it will help others dip their toes in the F# waters, too.