# Implement C# Async Interface with F#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, interface, f#

I have to implement a C# interface with F#.  The interface and many of the methods I have to use are all written with C# and use async very heavily.

Example code to port from C# to F#:

```
public async Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Processor Shuting Down.  Partition '{0}', Reason: '{1}'.", this.partitionContext.Lease.PartitionId, reason.ToString()));
    if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown)
    {
        await context.CheckpointAsync();
    }
}
```

This can be problematic, as F# and C# do not use the same async pattern or types.  The function above is part of an interface that I need to implement.  My issue comes in how do I await `context.CheckpointAsync()` with F# in such a way that it still returns a `Task`.

This is the direction I was attempting to go, however it does not work.  `context.CheckpointAsync` returns `Task<a>` not `Task`.  Additionally, what about the other cases, in which no operation is expected?

```ml
interface IEventProcessor with
    member this.CloseAsync(context:PartitionContext, reason:CloseReason) =
        match reason with
        | CloseReason.Shutdown -> context.CheckpointAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        | _ -> ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Task is also an IAsyncResult which means you can use Async.AwaitIAsyncResult and ignore the output.

Wrap it all in an async computation expression, start it as a Task<unit> then cast to Task.

```
interface IEventProcessor with

    member __.CloseAsync(context : PartitionContext, reason : CloseReason) = 
        async { 
            if reason = CloseReason.Shutdown then 
                do! context.CheckpointAsync() |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult |> Async.Ignore
        }
        |> Async.StartAsTask :> Task
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in C# this has a return type of `Task` rather than `Task<T>`. In a perfect world C# could have `Task<void>`.

F#3.x has built in bindings for going from `Task<T>` to `Async<T>` but not from pla `Task` to `Async<T>`. There are samples of that on SO e.g. [How to Async.AwaitTask on plain Task (not Task<T>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022909/how-to-async-awaittask-on-plain-task-not-taskt)

At any rate, it would be helpful to see the exact error you get but here looks like your error is that you're trying to `Async.AwaitTask` (which will return `Async<T>`) yet the interface must be `Task`. So you can just get rid of the `Async.AwaitTask()` completely.

Then you're going to get another error that the match cases don't tie up i.e. the `Shutdown` branch returns `Task`, whereas the other branch returns `unit`. You need to change that to return a `Task` as well.

Comment: This seems like cheating...
                
    member this.CloseAsync(context:PartitionContext,     reason:CloseReason) =
                    match reason with
                    | CloseReason.Shutdown -> context.CheckpointAsync()
                    | _ -> 
                        let a = new System.Action(fun t -> ())
                        new Task(a)

Comment: On this note, I got OpenAsync to work, but having issues with ProcessEventsAsync and CloseAsync.  The magic wiring doesn't appear to be working.  Open async returns a task, but is not marked with the async prefix like Close and Process are.

Comment: Why is that cheating?

BTW - it won't be marked with the async modifier; AFAIK F# won't generate methods with that modifier. And you're not doing any async code inside this method anyway - all you're doing is returning a task from a child method. There's no awaiting or let! anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid using async and return the task from `CheckpointAsync` directly:

```
match reason with
| CloseReason.Shutdown -> context.CheckpointAsync() :> Task
| _ -> Task.CompletedTask
```