# Why does casting a value declaration instead of a function argument result in different behavior?

Tags: f#, lego-mindstorms

Why does casting a value declaration instead of a function argument result in different behavior?

**The following operation hangs:**

```
let duration = uint32 500
...
brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(motors, power, duration, breakEnabled) |> ignore
```

**The following operation succeeds:**

```
brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(motors, power, uint32 500, breakEnabled) |> ignore
```

What's the difference?

**Code:**

```
let volume = 100
let frequency = uint16 1000
let duration = uint32 500
let power = 100
let motors = OutputPort.B ||| OutputPort.C
let breakEnabled = false

let moveAsync = async {

    let brick = Brick(UsbCommunication())

    brick.ConnectAsync() |> ignore
    brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(motors, power, duration, breakEnabled) |> ignore

    }

Async.RunSynchronously moveAsync
```

Comment: I know it's a new day when you ask a new question. Are you going for the badge with one positive question a day for x days?

Comment: @ Guy Coder - Nope. Some people vote down my questions. I just really want to increase my worth. The more I learn, the more I practice, the more I demonstrate, the more I'm worth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is rather strange, you should [read up](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/) on how to use `async` workflow. That said, what I would expect - provided that your functions indeed return `Async<'a>` - is something like this:

```
let moveAsync = 
    async {
        let brick = Brick(UsbCommunication())

        do! brick.ConnectAsync() |> Async.Ignore
        let! _ = brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(motors, power, duration, breakEnabled)
    }
```

You want to use `let!` or `do!` to compose async workflows - if you have an `Async<'a>` and don't care about the return value, you can also use `Async.Ignore` to turn it into `Async<unit>` (rather than plain `ignore`).

**Edit:** To clarify why I gave this answer - I cannot even imagine a scenario where you would face the problem *as stated*.

But the code you posted clearly has problems that in my opinion **make it impossible to really reason about what is going on**. Like returning `Tasks` (that may have been started or not) inside an async workflow *without waiting for them to complete*. If what this code does meets your expectations, I feel it's only by coincidence.

My intuition is that once you sort out these problems, you'll see that whichever way you pass in the duration argument is fine.

Comment: Thanks @scrwtp - However, I get the following build error: 'Task' is not compatible with 'Async<'a>'

Comment: Well - in that case those functions return .NET `Tasks` rather then F# `Asyncs`, and you can't compose them directly.

Comment: Check this thread how to do deal with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022909/how-to-async-awaittask-on-plain-task-not-taskt

Comment: @ scrwtp  - Thank you for providing me guidance on recommended practices. I have updated my code to reflect your guidance. However, I still am not aware of the answer regarding the subject of the question. I can post a separate question for you to post the above answer to give you credit if you'd like.

Comment: Now that would clearly be putting the cart before the horse. Also, check the edit.