# How to do await an Async method, similar to C#

Tags: f#

How to do an simple **await** in F# ?

In C# I have code like this:

```
await collection.InsertOneAsync(DO);
var r = collection.ReplaceOneAsync((fun d -> d.Id = DO.Id), DO)
```

So I created a **let await = ...** to my F# code become more similar with my C# code.

My current F# code is this:

```
let awaits (t: Threading.Tasks.Task) = t |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
let await (t: Threading.Tasks.Task<'T>) = t |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously


let Busca (numero) = 
    let c = collection.Find(fun d -> d.Numero=numero).ToList()
    c

let Insere(DO: DiarioOficial) =
    //collection.InsertOneAsync(DO) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
    collection.InsertOneAsync(DO) |> awaits

let Salva (DO: DiarioOficial) =
    //let r = collection.ReplaceOneAsync((fun d -> d.Id = DO.Id), DO) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
    let r = collection.ReplaceOneAsync((fun d -> d.Id = DO.Id), DO) |> await
    r
```

I want to have only one definition for await (awaits), but the best I could do is this, because on Insere, type is Task, but on Salva, type is Task<'T>

If i use only the **await**, I get this compile error:

> FS0001    The type 'Threading.Tasks.Task' is not compatible with the type 'Threading.Tasks.Task<'a>'

If I use only the **awaits**, it compiles, but I lose the return type from the **async Task**
I want to merge the await and awaits in a single

```
let await = ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022909/how-to-async-awaittask-on-plain-task-not-taskt

Comment: None of them have a simple let await statement as I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

In F# we tend to use another syntax. It is described e.g. here: [https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/.](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/)

or here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/asynchronous-and-concurrent-programming/async

The idea of working with C# Tasks is to "convert" them to async with [Async.Await<'T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.awaittask%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D)

You can do it probably another way, but it is the most straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts of writing async code in both F# and C#.

- You need to mark the method or code block as asynchronous. In C#, this is done using the `async` keyword. The F# equivalent is to use the `async { ... }` block (which is an expression, but otherwise, it is similar).
- Inside `async` method or `async { .. }` block, you can make non-blocking calls. In C#, this is done using `await` and in F# it is done using `let!`. Note that this is not just a function call - the compiler handles this in a special way.

F# also uses `Async<T>` type rather than `Task<T>`, but those are easy to convert - e.g. using `Async.AwaitTask`. So, you probably want something like this:

```
let myAsyncFunction () = async {
  let! _ = collection.InsertOneAsync(DO) |> Async.AwaitTask
  let r = collection.ReplaceOneAsync((fun d -> d.Id = DO.Id), DO) 
  // More code goes here
}
```

I used `let!` to show the idea, but if you have an asynchronous operation that returns `unit`, you can also use `do!`

```
do! collection.InsertOneAsync(DO) |> Async.AwaitTask
```